# Getting Blank messages in my app from AWS SNS.

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I want to send push notification to individual using android GCM. have created the app in SNS. I am using aws-sdk v1.4 for Ruby.

When I send through Amazon web interface I receive the messages, but When I publish it through using the code below, I get blank messages. what is the right message format to send?

```
sns = AWS::SNS::Client.new
endpoint = sns.create_platform_endpoint(platform_application_arn:my_token)
sns.publish(target_arn:endpoint:endpoint_arn, message: "GCM:{data:{message:"GCM:{data:{message:'hello'}")
```

Please help.
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message should be a valid JSON string if you want to publish a message to GCM. You can use `to_json` to serialize a hash object to JSON. Here is a article about using AWS SDK for Ruby http://blog.tryneighborly.com/amazon-sns-for-apns-on-rails/.

For more information about Amazon SNS:

- [Send Custom Platform-Specific Payloads in Messages to Mobile Devices](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-custommessage.html)
- [Getting Started with Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html)
- [Ruby doc for Aws::SNS::Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/SNS/Client.html#publish-instance_method)

Comment: {"GCM"=>"{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"test123\" } }"}                                The above is my ruby hash for the json_message to send as push nitrification.  How can I convert this hash to correct (valid) json format as below  {
"GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"Hello\" } }"
}

Answer (score 1):

```
{"GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"hello\" } }"}
```

Do not call to_json method also set the subject parameter in publish.